# How can I avoid deprecated methods and maintain backwards compatibility?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, android-support-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with deprecated classes in Android to keep compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321649/how-to-deal-with-deprecated-classes-in-android-to-keep-compatibility)

I ran into the deprecated `Display.getWidth()` method and saw that it has been replaced with `android.view.getSize()`.  However `getSize()` has only been available since API 13 and `View` appears not to be included in the V4 Android support library.

So, if I want to avoid the deprecated calls, how can I do this without maintaining different projects/builds for various API levels.

Comment: Here is your solution 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10165103/614807

Comment: @ChiragRaval that is not a solution to this question.  That answer just states that it is "okay" to use deprecated methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `Display` object named `display`, this should work:

```
int width=-1;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    Point size=new Point();
    size=display.getSize(size);
    width=size.x;
}
else {
    width=display.getWidth();
}
```

IOW, use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to branch between the "before" and "after" cases for where a new API is introduced.

This will require your build target (Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to be set to API Level 13+, so you can call `getSize()`.

Comment: BTW, I am assuming that the width is `x` in a `Point` -- the documentation is decidedly fuzzy on this, um, point. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is an official Android developers class [Creating Backward-Compatible UIs](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html):

> This class demonstrates how to use UI components and APIs available in
>   newer versions of Android in a backward-compatible way, ensuring that
>   your application still runs on previous versions of the platform.

They advocate using Java interfaces for libraries that aren't back-ported to get a more object-oriented solution.  Then you extend these into two concrete classes: one that provides alternate behavior for unsupported platforms and one that calls the actual API for supported platforms.

Then there's a factory class that instantiates the correct class by checking the current platform against the supported platform range.  Ultimately though, it boils down to a conditional like `if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= HONEYCOMB_MR2 )`.