# Android Studio - how to find methods from APIs higher than min and what to do with them?

Tags: android, android-studio, compatibility

I am writing an app using AndroidStudio, targetting API 19, but with min API 14. I discovered that some of the methods I use are available from API 16+.

Is there a way in AndroidStudio to find all methods available from APIs higher than current minimum?

And what should I do with such calls? When I change them to compatibile with lower APIs, AS tells me that those methods are deprecated. So what can I do to support the older versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finding uses of apis above minimal SDK api use lint, with gradle this should be by default unless you have:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

in your build.gradle

If you want to use api that is from ie. KITKAT for given object then write it like that:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
   obj.kitkatAndAboveApi().
}
```

if you want to use some class from ie. KITKAT and above then you would have to write a wrapper class to avoid exceptions while loading unaviable class. This class would be responsible for loading this kitkat class and would be used by your app only on kitkat+.

You can sometimes also use reflection for querying if method exist and then call it.

Also you can take a look how its done in support library, ie. for backward compatible `MenuItem`:

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.java

---

some clarifications:

1. Under Android Studio 0.8.9 to see all uses of unaviable api's, use menu Analyze -> Inspect Code. In results you will have Android Lint -> 'Calling new methods on older versions'. This is where you will have a list of errors you should fix.
2. Build will fail if there are lint errors only if done from command line, ie.:

$ gradlew build

and only if you have not added `abortOnError false`. I dont know how to make AS fail on lint errors.

Comment: As Android Studio 0.8.9 it is not enabled by default, as I only saw the app crashing on the phone (it compiled and worked on higher-API emulator). As for checking for versions: should I always use it, or go for "deprecated" methods for both older and newer apis (this leaves less code, and it appears I am forced to use deprecated calls for compatibility anyway)

Comment: I added some clarifications. As for using deprecated methods, if you want ot be super clean then use the method versions appropriate for given platform. But before doing this read some more on SO (ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164896/is-it-ok-to-have-so-many-deprecated-methods-in-backward-compatible-code), some of the deprecated warnings can be suppressed.